# Which is better for Windows Phone Development - Silverlight or WinRT?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, windows-phone-silverlight

I have a Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight App. I do not need an Universal App. I just need my app to run on Windows Phone Devices. So, should I continue my app on the Silverlight platform or should I develop it on WinRT? Will having it developed on Silverlight be a problem in the near future? What are the pros and cons? Also, which has got more support on forums, which is more powerful and which is the one MS supports more?

Comment: Isn't silverlight like... dead?

Comment: but still it is used for developing Windows Phone Apps

Comment: If your application is using `clipboard` API, DON'T GO FOR winRT... [More information](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/thunbrynt/archive/2014/04/15/windows-phone-8-1-for-developers-choose-your-windows-phone-xaml-app-model.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Develop it as a Universal App, but have it target Mobile only. UWP (Universal Windows Platform) has more support now. RT & Silverlight are essentially obsolete.